# Htaccess redirect all if no specific useragent?

Tags: .htaccess

How to redirect all useragent except useragent wget ? what to add?

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent .*Wget* wget

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=wget
```

Comment: "Redirect" or _block_? What response do you want all non-wget requests to receive? What is currently happening with the code you posted?

Comment: in my code only useragent wget can access. I need redirect all user agent except wget

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a "redirecting" `ErrorDocument` directive to your existing directives. For example:

```
ErrorDocument 403 https://example.com/url/to/redirect/to
```

When combined with your existing directives (that "block" all other User-Agents) this will trigger a 302 (temporary) redirect to the stated URL for anything other than wget.

Alternatively, replace your existing directives with the following mod_rewrite rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Wget
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/url/to/redirect/to [R=302,L]
```

Both of these assume the URL you are redirecting to maps to a different server, otherwise, you'll like get a redirect loop.